# If someone punches a train seat clean off its hinges, is the Newton force pair magnitude the same?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I had a thought about this while on the train a few days back.

*Say someone decided to punch a seat in a train, which is bolted to the floor. Assuming someone punched the seat so hard, and neglecting any torque - that the punch was at the chair's center of mass and so great that the torque applied by the bolt to the chair was applied so briefly that it was negligible since that pure force of the punch decoupled the chair completely almost immediately.*

Say the punch packed a payload of one million Newtons. When the contact is made, does the chair apply one million Newtons to the fist, or merely the minimum amount of force required to free the chair from its coupling to the train's floor?

If it delivers the full force pair force of one million Newtons back to the fist, where does this force come from for the chair? How does it have such potential? Because the fist hit it? What if the fist hit a feather at the same force? Would the feather apply the same force (assuming this occurs in a vacuum, so any air current created by the fist divert the contact)?

Answer (score 1):

> Say the punch packed a payload of one million Newtons. When the contact is made, does the chair apply one million Newtons to the fist

Yes! This is Newton's Third law. No way around it.

> or merely the minimum amount of force required to free the chair from its coupling to the train's floor?

It doesn't matter the coupling force, because even when there is no coupling force at all, your *assumption* is that if your punch packs 1MN. So 1MN will be delivered to the chair (and start accelerating its mass) and 1MN will be received by the fist, slowing it down or absobing energy from whatever it is that is providing it its incredible punch.

> If it delivers the full force pair force of one million Newtons back to the fist, where does this force come from for the chair?

Any object can provide any amount of reaction force.

- If the object (chair) is not attached to anything, the force will make that object accelerate. The more force, the more acceleration.
- If the object (chair) is bolted to something (train), that something will accelerate as well. Again, the more force, the more acceleration.
- If the object (chair) is bolted to something (train) that is bolted to whatever produces the force (you), then the force flows on a loop: fist -> chair -> train -> you -> fist, and no external force is applied to the complete system (you+fist+chair+train), therefore nothing happens.

This circle is like when you tighten a pincer : you're providing force on both blades, which cancel out and the pincer doesn't fly away.

> How does it have such potential?

The chair has no special 'potential' in this context (potential is the ability to deliver energy). Your fist has potential, because you made it magically pack 1MN punch (amazing workout btw!) regardless of what happens.

However the chair, like any object, can receive force, and start moving (accelerate). This will increase its kinetic energy. Any object can receive energy in the form of kinetic energy, be it a chair, a train, or an apple.

> What if the fist hit a feather at the same force? Would the feather apply the same force (assuming this occurs in a vacuum, so any air current created by the fist divert the contact)?

Stick to your assumption. You're assuming 1MN punch. So the feather receives 1MN. It weighs 1g, so it starts to accelerate (at a blazing A=F/m=1 000 000 000 m/s²,s see you later, feather). As long as your assumption holds (1MN punch), the feather will keep accelerating. Note that it would gather a lot of kinetic energy, and your arm will ge tired quickly. Note you'll have to make sure your fist stays in contact to keep applying the force, so it too will have to accelerate quite a lot.

But with your amazing workout, that shouldn't be a problem!

**TL;DR**: You made an assumption (1MN punch). Stick to it, don't try to waive the results away.

Answer (score 0):

IF the fist applies the million Newton force to something, the same force is applied to the fist. The two forces are simultaneous and they are the result of the same interaction. There is no point to ask where the force on the fist come from. It comes from the same source as the force exerted by the fist.
But the force applied when you hit something depends on the inertia of the other body as well as on the constraints applied to the second body. You can apply more force if the chair is attached than if it moves away as soon as you touch it. For this reason is very unlikely for you to apply that huge force to a feather. Unless you punch it against a wall or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are considering your examples from the wrong point of view ie applying a force of a given magnitude.

When you punch something the momentum of your fist (and arm etc) will change $\Delta p$ over a time $\Delta t$.
To make the analysis easier imagine that the force $F$, acting on the fist due to some object which changes the momentum of the fist, is constant.

$F\Delta t =\Delta p$

In turn, applying Newton's third law, the fist is applying an equal magnitude and opposite direction force on the object.

If the seat in anchored then the distance the fist moves whilst slowing down is very small and it occurs over a short period of time.
This means that the forces involved during the interaction between the fist and the seat are large.
So large that the chances are that the force the seat exerts on the fist will do damage to the fist.
If the seat is not anchored then the interaction will occur over a larger distance as the seat will move further during its interaction with the fist and hence over a longer time so the forces involved would be smaller.

When you punch a feather because the mass of the feather is so small and also because the feather deforms so easily the force that your fist exerts on the feather is small - a small change in the momentum of the feather over a comparative long period of time during which the interaction occurs.
In effect your fist cannot exert a million Newton's on the feather unless you could get your fist to move incredibly fast which would increase the change of momentum of the feather and reduce the interaction time.